# What exactly is wrong with my if statements?

Tags: c++

I've tried different ways of laying out my if statements, I even tried nested if statements. I get the same result. I'm not sure of any way to ask my question besides showing my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
char playerOne, playerTwo;

cout<<"ROCK PAPER SCISSORS!"<<endl;
cout<<"Enter P for Paper"<<endl;
cout<<"Enter R for Rock"<<endl;
cout<<"Enter S for Scissors"<<endl;

cout<<"Player One enter your choice: ";
cin>>playerOne;

cout<<"Player Two enter your choice: ";
cin>>playerTwo;

if ((playerOne = 'R') && (playerTwo = 'R'))
    cout<<"Both players played same hand";
else if ((playerOne = 'R') && (playerTwo = 'P'))
    cout<<"Player Two wins!";
else if ((playerOne = 'R') && (playerTwo = 'S'))
    cout<<"Player One wins!";
else if ((playerOne = 'P') && (playerTwo = 'R'))
    cout<<"Player One wins!";
else if ((playerOne = 'P') && (playerTwo = 'P'))
    cout<<"Both players played same hand";
else if ((playerOne = 'P') && (playerTwo = 'S'))
    cout<<"Player Two wins!";
else if ((playerOne = 'S') && (playerTwo = 'R'))
    cout<<"Player Two wins!";
else if ((playerOne = 'S') && (playerTwo = 'P'))
    cout<<"Player One wins!";
else if ((playerOne = 'S') && (playerTwo = 'S'))
    cout<<"Both players played same hand";
else
    cout<<"Invalid inputs!";

getche();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You might start by telling what is wrong with them, so that we can help you understand how to fix it.

Comment: The compiler should have generated some warnings with this code, did you pay any attention to them?

Answer (score 12):

you need the double `==` sign instead of `=`

`==` can be read as "is equal to"

Answer (score 6):

You must use `==` and not `=`. Operator `==` test for equality and operator `=` is assignment operator

By using `=` you are assigning and not testing for equality. Thus the condition always evaluates to true as assignment is successful UNLESS the value being assigned is (or effectively is) 0. (Thanks to pickypg)

Comment: something you should clarify: `variable = "blah";` returns true depending on what the lefthand is set to I believe (at least in php and javascript) and not just because it'll be successful

Comment: This is not true. It will evaluate to `false` if the value is (or effectively is) `0`.

Comment: In C and C++ `variable = "blah"` evaluates to `"blah"` if it's used as an expression (and that's a non null `char*` so in an `if` it will always be true). In general an assignment, when used as an expression, evaluates to the right hand side. And a value is always true unless it is `0`, `NULL` or `false`.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, you need `==`.

However, there are some practices to help here.

First, always put constants and function return values first.  `if('R' = playerOne...)` will fail to compile and tell you exactly where to find this.

Second, consider doing `tolower()` on the inputs (and lower-casing your constants) to allow `'R'` and `'r'` without having to test both.

Third, you could remove several if-statements with `if(playerOne == playerTwo)`.  Unfortunately, that requires a validity check on the input first to avoid both players entering the same invalid character.  However, you might wish this check in case there is an error typing, such as the first character typing 'ERRR' which invalidates (with your code) the 'ER' and then runs 'RR'.

Fourth, you might use hard-coded arrays or `std::map` etc. to encode the data and use it without all the if statements.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, you would want to use `==`.

The `==` is to check for equality, where `=` is an assignment operator like `int num = 1;`

And in your case, `==` is the operator you need.